# Typescript compiler: Cannot find name 'Map'

Tags: angular, typescript, electron

I have Electron + Angular app. I would like to use Typescript for Electron, so I have main.ts file and want to compile it to main.js using 'tsc main.ts'. However, I get the following error:

node_modules/@types/selenium-webdriver/remote.d.ts:139:29 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

Still main.js is generated and can be used when i run electron without tsc command. However, I would like it run by one script without any error.

My tsconfig.json contains:

```
{
 "compileOnSave": false,
 "compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": "./",
  "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "declaration": false,
  "module": "es2015",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "target": "es5",
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
   ],
  "lib": [
   "es2017",
   "dom"
  ]
 }
}
```

I've already tried various combinations of target and lib configuration (e.g. es6) but with no success.

Can anybody please help?
Many thanks!

Comment: Your target and lib properties are fine. It's probably something to do with typeRoots. Perhaps the library depends on a version of the nodejs types or something and it is installed in a subdirectory due to multiple versions

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you run `tsc main.ts`, your `tsconfig.json` file is not being used.  Instead run `tsc -p .` or simply `tsc`, and if necessary, restrict the input files to the compilation using the `files`, `include`, and `exclude` options in `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Many thanks Matt, solved by changing command to just `tsc` and by adding `include` and `exclude` sections before `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json`

Comment: @MichalPinka, I am facing the same error, can you show me your tsconfig.json file..??

Comment: @METALHEAD `{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "include": [
    "main.ts",
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}`

Answer (score 12):

For some reason, when I added the include and exclude sections as above, I still got errors:

```
"../node_modules/@types/selenium-webdriver/http.d.ts:24:14 - error TS2583: Cannot find name 'Map'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to es2015 or later"
```

The errors stopped when I ran: `npm i @types/node`

I would love to know why (:

Comment: `npm i @types/node` worked for me too , where did you find this in documentation, i would like to read more

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue after upgrading from Angular 6 to Angular 8. Turns out the upgrade script updates the Typescript version, but the `@types/node` package was outdated in my package.json (and apparently, not compatible anymore with the new Typescript version).
Updating it did the trick !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your library name is similar at .json file
Install npm gulp and ci

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.

Try to execute the following command:

```
npm ci
```

On my PC it fixed